# Keeping typesetting details in Markdown file

Tags: pandoc, workflow

I have written my text in Markdown, and now it's time to start typesetting it with LaTeX. I'd like to keep the Markdown sources as the ultimate source, because I want to be able to keep changes to the content and changes to the formatting in sync. Later on, I might want to use the same Markdown input to export to other formats for electronic publication, such as HTML, EPUB/MOBI, or LeanPub's Markdown variant.

One example of the "micromanagement" I'm thinking of is fiddling with spaces, such as using `~` and `\,` where appropriate. If I just write a `~` in a Markdown input, Pandoc of course converts it into `\textasciitilde`.

I'm looking for ideas on a workflow that allows me to fine-tune the typesetting but still keeps the Markdown as the source.

Comment: for the specific case of no break space you could use U+00A0  &nbsp; in html or however you enter the character `[ ]` in your editor.

Comment: Rmarkdown allow including LaTeX code that  in general  is passed as is to  LaTeX/PDF output but will be ignored in HTML outputs. And it can include  HMTL code that will be ignored in LaTeX/PDF outputs. But    `\ ` and  `&nbsp;`  are  exceptions that should work in both outputs.

Answer (score 3):

My series on [Typesetting Markdown](https://dave.autonoma.ca/blog/2019/05/22/typesetting-markdown-part-1/) may be of interest. The entire series has a focus on how to keep content (Markdown) separate from the typesetting logic (e.g., ConTeXt, LaTeX, or other).

The following example was typeset using ConTeXt, but the source files are 99.9% pure Markdown, with a few inline images annotated using pandoc's `:::` syntax (inline images are not shown here):

[image: Prolonged Bombardment]

[Part 8](https://dave.autonoma.ca/blog/2020/04/28/typesetting-markdown-part-8/) of my series includes a section on using annotations.

Running bash scripts to recompile the document each time quickly grows tedious. To that end, I have developed a text editor---called [KeenWrite](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite)---that provides a rough, real-time preview of the content rendered as an HTML document. The editor can export a themed PDF by leveraging user-defined `.tex` files that instruct [ConTeXt](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/) how to typeset the document.

Annotations in the preview pane are handled using `<div style="limerick">` elements and corresponding CSS. Annotations in ConTeXt are mapped to start/stop environments based on the annotation's class name (e.g., `\startlimerick` and `\stoplimerick`), which the [user must define](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite-themes/blob/main/boschet/poems.tex).

The [PDF themes](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite/blob/master/docs/screenshots.md#pdf-themes) screenshot depicts the same source document being rendered multiple ways:

[image: KeenWrite Themes]

As a bonus, KeenWrite can edit R Markdown files, as well. This affords the possibility of adding the results of computations into documents. If you're feeling particularly plucky, you can combine variables, R, and near real-time rendering of text-based diagrams. I use this feature to create a family tree for characters in a novel. Changing any character name will automatically cause the diagram to re-render with the revised name:

[image: KeenWrite Diagrams]

On a minor technical note, documents are typeset by first transforming the Markdown into XHTML. ConTeXt has excellent support for XML documents, allowing them to be styled and rendered into PDF documents.